# Get shortcode value from it returned in Custom field by wpBakery

Tags: wordpress, shortcode, visual-composer

Wordpress wpBakery visual composer shortcode `Custom field` is returning value as `{{ post_meta_value:"" 2 "mins }}` instead of `2 mins`

Here is the shortcode

```
[rt_reading_time label="" postfix="mins" postfix_singular="min"]
```

And it works fine in normal text editor but not in `Custom field`.

My question here now is how can I display `2 mins` instead as `{{ post_meta_value:"" 2 "mins }}` ?

The `Custom field`.
[image]
The web-page output.
[image]

The one i circled with 1 is the result from the normal rich text editor, but it only got it reading from current homepage and from not the item meta post.

While the one circled 2 is the right one but it returned as object instead of the main value.

Comment: What is this "Custom Field" Element? did you add/code it? Because i dont see it in our setups.   Anyway, the field where you put your shortcode, it actually asks for a field-NAME. so, this seems all kind of wrong.    can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: I don't add code to it! I found it inside vs grid builder. here is the screenshot https://prnt.sc/mcrahb

Comment: ah, the grid builder. ok. but this element and field is ment to contain a field-name, not some shortcode. if you want to output a shortcode, use a normal "Text Block " element in the grid builder.

Comment: I ended up using `google heading custom field` just as `custom field` and it worked fine. For `Text Block` it gives current page read time instead of the item post